# IIS can't install custom module

Tags: asp.net, iis, window, iis-manager, iis-modules

i'm trying since hours to install a custom module on IIS from the manager.
I coded it in C#.

I'm able to load it into a test ASP.NET app that i created.
I copy it into the bin folder, and add this line into the web.config :

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="Module" type="IISExtend.Module"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

It works.

---

To add it to IIS, i tried :

1. Put the output DLL into the bin folder of the root of the website, like this : https://i.gyazo.com/14b54742cc758d6083a9787df8a8cbe1.png
2. Add it in the module list like this : https://i.gyazo.com/b686a505c8d4785ffb63d5c384580ac5.png
   But i get this warning : https://i.gyazo.com/b137ecca9369cc53018aecd7409d8737.png

I already tried to edit config files manually, sign the dll, add it to global store, change the .NET version, and it changes nothing.
The module does not loads, and seems not installed.

Here the exact name of my class : https://i.gyazo.com/10973b6852e1d1de139641905bee2b19.png

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Did you install the assembly to GAC?

Comment: Yes, i tried, i signed it and installed it trought a command line

Comment: Then which GAC did you install it to? v2.x or v4.x? Also what version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0

I'm using Windows 10 PRO

Comment: Please refer to the official examples.  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework

Comment: You need to add the module to both, this might help https://serverfault.com/a/974599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
I installed a lot of windows features, regarding ASP.NET and ASP.NET core under IIS section.
I worked.

Thank you for your help.